# Change typeface of first chacater in cell - Excel, VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to change the font/typeface of the first character of a cell in excel. I've seen instructions on how to change the color, but I don't know enough VBA to change the typeface.

I have a formula that creates a cell like this: "ABC-Wbe-001".  I need to put a wingding character in front of this string. Since the wingding translates to the letter "l", i assume I need to add the letter 'l' in front, and use code to change the font of the first character only.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the characters in a range object.

```
Range("A1").Characters(start:=1, length:=1).Font.name = "Wingdings" 
'or whatever the name you want is.  Change the start and length as needed
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I notice that when I use a range of cells rather than a single cell, the formatting applies to the whole cell instead of just the first character. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: In my test it only changed the first character of each cell with text already in it. If the cell was blank then the default font for that cell was changed.  What's your situation?  My test was `Range("A1:B2").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.Name = "Wingdings"` Cells A1, B1 worked as expected.  Cells A2, B2 were blank to start and they would default to Wingdings.

Comment: It looks like the issue had nothing to do with your code, but instead another macro I was running prior to it was causing the entire range to change to wingdings font. I have it set now so that the macro I run before the one you gave me resets the font to Arial first, and everything works great now.